# What deity do celestials/aasimars worship?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, religions-and-deities, aasimar

I am creating an aasimar character who is devoted not only to her father's (celestial) faith but also to the preservation of nature. However, while making this character, I realized that, although I can find a lot of information about who these races are and what they do (as well as hidden lore about blood aasimar and the birth of their celestial parents), I have not found much about the deities celestials serve.

**Do celestials/aasimars all serve one deity, or if they can serve any deity as long as their alignment is good?**

More specifically for my case, I am considering Arawai, goddess of fertility, as she's about life and nature, though she's a Neutral Good deity from the Eberron setting.

Comment: Are you asking for a lore or a rules answer? I don't think there are any rules on it.

Comment: rules mostly. cant find celestial info for 5e

Comment: Are you asking about aasimars or celestials? I think you may need to split the question.

Comment: @NautArch As far as I could understand, celestials are the aasimars' guides. As such, I took it for granted that the student would worship the same deity as the master kinda thing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## There are no rules for worshiping gods, but likely a lawful good god

Aasimar are found in the Volo's Guide to Monsters and the relevant part of their description is below:

> Aasimar bear within their souls the light of the heavens. They are descended from humans with a touch of the power of Mount Celestia, the divine realm of many lawful good deities. Aasimar are born to serve as champions of the gods, their births hailed as blessed events.

The description is "champions of the gods", gods in general with no specific reference made to a particular deity. The only guidance we are given is that Mount Celestia is home to mostly lawful good deities. The next section also assumes this:

> Aasimar are placed in the world to serve as guardians of law and good. Their patrons expect them to strike at evil, lead by example, and further the cause of justice.

Although this is descriptive text the assumption is that most Aasimar will follow a lawful good deity. This doesn't have to be the case however, since the description goes on to mention their conflicted souls:

> Despite its celestial origin, an aasimar is mortal and possesses free will. Most aasimar follow their ordained path, but some grow to see their abilities as a curse. These disaffected aasimar are typically content to turn away from the world, but a few become agents of evil. In their minds, their exposure to celestial powers amounted to little more than brainwashing.

Remember however, that this is only guidance and there is no restriction on the alignment, deity or class of any race in 5th edition. What gods exist in your world is up to your DM and you can work with them to decide which suits your character best. If you choose to be an archetypical aasimar that would likely be a lawful good god but you aren't required to follow this.

---

As for celestials, they are a creature type not a race. Therefore guidance on what god they are likely to follow is hard to find. The stat entries for most celestials are lawful good, though some (Pegasus) are chaotic good.

Generally celestials are good aligned and would worship a good or lawful good god if they worship one at all. Despite being basically angels themselves celestials are no more or less required to worship than any other creature type.

Comment: Aasimar can be descendant from evil gods as readily as from good gods; this puts a dent in the "inherent goodness in their blood".
I don't see a descendant from Serenrei having the same moral outlook as one sired by Asmodeus, if it has any effect at all

Comment: @ThisIsMe Where are you sourcing that from? I'm quoting the class description from Volo's which says they have a piece of the power from Mount Celestia which is a home to Lawful Good gods.

Comment: A descendant of Asmodeus would be a Tiefling

Comment: @ThisIsMe VGtM p. 105 points rather directly toward Celestia; evil gods don't tend to come from there.

Comment: @NautArch Updated to include celestial information. Will add more if I can find a source but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 18):

### Celestials and aasimar can be connected to any (or no) deity

To start with, celestials are simply a specific type of creature. An extremely wide range of creatures fit into the [category of celestial](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=3&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=) including some which are entirely disconnected from deities in their creation or patronage. One example is the Pegasus which simply hails from a plane wherein some deities reside:

> Pegasi trace their origins to the Olympian Glades of Arborea, where they soar through the skies of that plane and serve as faithful mounts to the Seldarine, the pantheon of elven gods.
>
> [Monster Manual]

Aasimar are also just influenced by planar power (not necessarily power from any deity) through ancestry:

> They are descended from humans with a touch of the power of Mount Celestia
>
> [Volo's Guide to Monsters]

Many aasimar do serve the ideals of law and good, but fallen aasimar do exist, and no single deity can claim inherent ownership of any aasimar.

In conclusion, **any deity is eligible to be connected to a celestial or aasimar**.

Comment: this might be a case of me missing a point... is a celestial an independent race or a servant race? for my question, I am focused on the angels (as I don't believe Aasmirs can be born from a human shacking a pegasus) and I thought I read the name Aasmir means something like "one who serves" and can also be the name of normas?

Comment: @VictorB in 5e's lexicon, aasimar are not necessarily descendent from celestial by blood (though I suppose they could be), but must only be connected to the plane in question (and share some of that plane's power). Celestial as a whole are just a creature category, each one with their own origins

Comment: Isn't Volo 5e? In there doesn't it say that Aasimar are the opposite of tieflings, having celestial rather than infernal blood?

Comment: @VictorB no. That's where my quote for "They are descended from...." comes from. No mention of them being the opposite of tiefling or having celestial blood.

Answer (score 8):

To reference Volo's Guide to Monsters specifically:

> Aasimar are placed in the world to serve as guardians of law and good.
>   Their patrons expect them to strike at evil, lead by example, and
>   further the cause of justice. From an early age, an aasimar receives
>   visions and guidance from celestial entities via dreams. These dreams
>   help shape an aasimar, granting a sense of destiny and a desire for
>   righteousness. Each aasimar can count a specific celestial agent of
>   the gods as a guide. This entity is typically a deva, an angel who
>   acts as a messenger to the mortal world. (VGtM, p. 105)

Also found on the same page of Volo's Guide to Monsters:

> Aasimar bear within their souls the light of the heavens. They are descended from humans with a touch of the power of Mount Celestia, the divine realm of many lawful good deities. Aasimar are born to serve as champions of the gods, their births hailed as blessed events. They are a people of otherworldly visages, with luminous features that reveal their celestial heritage. (VGtM, p. 105)

From all of this we can gather that Aasimars are descendants of various deities, and are guided by various others, so basically it's up to you (or your DM) what dieties have ties to any given Aasimar.

Comment: When making quotes, please use quote formatting to make your answer easier to read.

Comment: Op also asked about Celestials, can you include that in your answer?